# Can't get the current page as parameter when the next button is clicked

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to get the page number as a parameter when the **next** button is clicked.

I'm trying to achieve it using the below code:

```javascript
onPaging: function(pgButton) {
    if(pgButton == "next") {
        window.alert("next clicked! \n page: " + 
                     $('#userlist').getGridParam('page'));
    }
}
```

without any success(with the above code the **next** button is not working). I'm sure that I'm missing something really simple. Is there a specific place in the grid code, where I should place my code?

Comment: Why do you have a `+` in your code? Remove that...

Comment: I have also tried with just: `window.alert("next clicked!");` , but the result was the same, the next button is not responding when it's clicked.

Comment: You didn't intend to put that `)` after `page: `

Comment: got the same result, I belive that there is a specific place where the code should be placed, but I have no idea where... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
onPaging: function(pgButton){ if(pgButton=="next_your_paging_tool_id"){ window.alert("next clicked! \n page: " + $('#userlist').getGridParam('page')); } },
```

append the ID of your paging tool ID with a _ in your if condition as in the code posted

Comment: is there a specific place, where I can place it, or it can go anywhare in the grid declaration code?

Comment: What is the ID of your paging tool ?

Comment: it's `pager`, if I'm not mistaking. This is my very first jquery code.

Comment: then you should replace the code in if condition with this pgButton=="next_pager"

Answer (score 1):

`pgButton` is a `String`. You should write `if (pgButton == "next")`. See: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#events