# How to get the event when [enter] is ressed in pginput

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This question is related to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118444/cant-get-the-current-page-as-parameter-when-the-next-button-is-clicked) question

I'm trying to get the page as a parameter, when the user inserts the page number into the `pginput` box and when the enter key is pressed.

I already have the code which alerts me and which is passing the parameters to a controller. What I need is a small clue, on how to execute the code when the enter key is pressed while the cursor is in the `pginput` box.

Is it possible?

EDIT

Last code:

```
onPaging: function(pgButton){ 
            //var status = returnUserStatus();
            window.alert("enter pressed \n page: " + page);
            if(pgButton=="next_pager"){ 
                var page = $('#userslist').getGridParam("page");
                window.alert("next clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                //loadUsers(userStatus, page);
            } 
            if(pgButton=="prev_pager"){ 
                var page = $('#userslist').getGridParam("page");
                window.alert("prev clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                //loadUsers(userStatus, page);
            } 
            if(pgButton=="last_pager"){ 
                var page = $('#userslist').getGridParam("page");
                window.alert("last clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                //loadUsers(userStatus, page);              
            }
            if(pgButton=="first_pager"){ 
                var page = $('#userslist').getGridParam("page");
                window.alert("first clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                //loadUsers(userStatus, page);
            }
        },
```

Comment: Actually onPaging event will capture the enter key press in the pginput box so what is the need of the another function to detect enter key press

Comment: I need to execute some code when the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
                   onPaging: function(pgButton){ 
                                //var status = returnUserStatus();

                                if(pgButton=="next_pager"){ 
                                    var page = $('#userslist').getGridParam("page");
                                    window.alert("next clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                                    //loadUsers(userStatus, page);
                                } 
                                else if(pgButton=="prev_pager"){ 
                                    var page = $('#userslist').getGridParam("page");
                                    window.alert("prev clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                                    //loadUsers(userStatus, page);
                                } 
                                else if(pgButton=="last_pager"){ 
                                    var page = $('#userslist').getGridParam("page");
                                    window.alert("last clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                                    //loadUsers(userStatus, page);              
                                }
                                else if(pgButton=="first_pager"){ 
                                    var page = $('#userslist').getGridParam("page");
                                    window.alert("first clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                                    //loadUsers(userStatus, page);
                                }else {
                                    window.alert("enter pressed \n page: " );
                                }
                            },
```

Comment: Is your alert inside if condition ? Put the alert outside any condition

Comment: Ok, but now I cann see the alert `enter was pressed` when I click on any button. Is there a way to show the message only when enter is pressed? ps. I have edited the post, so you will be able to see the actual code I'm using rite now.

Comment: It's always showing `enter was pressed` because if `if(pgButton=="first_pager")` is not executed the else statement is active

Comment: got it working with `}else if((pgButton !="first_pager") && (pgButton !="last_pager") && (pgButton !="prev_pager") && (pgButton !="next_pager"))  
    window.alert("enter pressed \n page: "+ page );` thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#pginput").keypress(function(e)
 {
  if(e.keyCode==13)//pressing `Enter`
  {
   //do something
  }
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: Is there a specific place where I should add this code? I can't get it working. :(

Comment: You can add it anywhere in the `$(document).ready();` function. It should work fine. Please check your code for other errors.