# Can't get the 'page' parameter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This question is related to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118444/cant-get-the-current-page-as-parameter-when-the-next-button-is-clicked) question.
What I have so far is:

```
onPaging: function(pgButton){ 
            var status = returnUserStatus();
            var pageNum = $('#userslist').getGridParam('page');
            if(pgButton=="next_pager"){ 
                //window.alert("next clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                loadUsers(status, pageNum);
            } 
            if(pgButton=="prev_pager"){ 
                //window.alert("prev clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                loadUsers(status, pageNum);
            } 
            if(pgButton=="last_pager"){ 
                //window.alert("last clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                loadUsers(status, pageNum);             
            }
            if(pgButton=="first_pager"){ 
                //window.alert("first clicked! \n page: " + page); 
                loadUsers(status, pageNum);
            }else if((pgButton !="first_pager") && (pgButton !="last_pager") && (pgButton !="prev_pager") && (pgButton !="next_pager"))     
                //window.alert("enter pressed \n page: "+ page );

                console.log(pageNum);
                loadUsers(status, pageNum);
        },
```

The problem is that the I can't get it when enter is clicked(in the testing above) for unknown reason the variable `pageNum` is `undefined`.

Please, help me! I'm trying to fix this issue since 2-3 days

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem

Comment: The problem is that I can not reach the 'page' parameter and get it value

Comment: you've already stated the problem..where's the demo?

Comment: So many questions not answered here. 1) what version of jqgrid; 2) any message in the console? (press F12); Is "userslist" unique and spelled correctly?

Comment: @mplungjan not sure about the version as I'm working on an existing project, the console says `undefined`, userslist is correct and unique

Comment: @Slim: If you just open `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` you will see the version of jqGrid in the comment at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page number can be get by the following code

```
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
    var pageNumber = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "page");
    alert(pageNumber);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exacly what I was looking for! Thanks again!

Comment: I down voted it cause it doesn't work in latest version of JQGird , cause the latest version of JQGrid returns the current page no only in onPagign event.

Comment: @Vipresh: In the question the user used `$('#userslist')` and get `undefined` value. It was the main problem. The `page` parameter is **always defined to some non-negative value**. So I supposed that the user just used *copy* from another code. I know no other cases when `$('#userslist').getGridParam('page');` will be `undefined`. Usage of `$(this)` fixed the problem. I suppose that you have **another** problem. Or you do get still `undefined` value if you use `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "page")` inside of `onPaging`?

Comment: @Oleg Your are right in mentioning that "The page parameter is always defined to some non-negative value", but in your above answer you have explicitly mentioned that the method call .jqGrid("getGridParam", "page") in the onPaging event gives "New Page Number" which doesn't work in latest versoin of JQGrid, I think you or some one with proper rights should edit your answer and provide enough info regarding the versions in which the method call will give new page. If you still feel I wrongly down voted your reply I will revert it.

Comment: @Vipresh: Sorry, but the question was not about **"New Page Number"**. It's clear that in the least versions of jqGrid the order of changing `page` parameter is changed and now one have to calculate it in another way, but it's not the problem which had the user who asked *the question*. See exactly: **The problem is that the I can't get it when enter is clicked(in the testing above) for unknown reason the variable `pageNum` is `undefined`**. So my answer explain how solve *the problem* and not how to update code of another answer to new version of jqGrid.

Comment: @Vipresh: I suppose that you have more problem with the answer on [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14118444/315935) and not with my.

Comment: @Vipresh: If you don't lake the name of variables I can change it.

Answer (score 4):

Vipresh is right.

This code:

```
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
    var pageNumber = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "page");
    alert(pageNumber);
    //...
}
```

Would have alerted the new page number in previous versions of the jqGrid, but is now alerting the old page number instead, which is quite useless at my own opinion.

Here is what I had to do in order to get the new page number with the latest version of jqGrid:

```
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
    var newUserValue = $('input.ui-pg-input', "#pg_pagerId").val();
    var newValue = 0;
    var currentValue = $("#gridId").getGridParam('page');
    if (pgButton.indexOf("next") >= 0)
        newValue = ++currentValue;
    else if (pgButton.indexOf("prev") >= 0)
        newValue = --currentValue;
    else if (pgButton.indexOf("last") >= 0)
        newValue = $("#gridId").getGridParam('lastpage');
    else if (pgButton.indexOf("first") >= 0)
        newValue = 1;
    else if (pgButton.indexOf("user") >= 0)
        newValue = newUserValue;
    alert(newValue);
},
```